# BigQuery: query cross region

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a situation like below: I want to run a query against a table of my **dataset in EU** and to write its result into a table of my **dataset in US**. Is it possible to do that via the **BigQuery REST resource**, please ?

In fact, I run my query via a [job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job) with `location` in [jobReference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/JobReference) = 'EU', BQ can execute sucessfully the query but it cannot write the result into my table of **dataset in US**. BQ gave me this error

```
 Not found: Dataset dummy_project:dataset_us was not found in location EU
```

Do you guys have any idea, please?

Thank you !!!

Answer (score 9):

You can't perform cross region query. You must have your data in the same region to query them.

The solution is to use the [BigQuery data transfer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs) to copy a dataset to another one (in the correct region). You haven't no other solution than duplicating all the data in the dataset (no possible to select only a table) to another region (and therefore to pay the data storage and the inter region network traffic)

Comment: I do understand now, thank @guillaume !!